# How can you process a newline escape sequence "\n" in a SwiftUI TextField as a line break?

Tags: swiftui, escaping, newline, textfield

I am trying to create a simple text field that allows inputs with newline sequences and outputs the text with line breaks.

```
struct Foo: View {
  @State private var inputText: String

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      TextField("foo", text: $inputText)
      Text(inputText)
    }
  }
}
```

Newline sequences work fine in `Text("hello\nworld")` but will simply display the "\n" instead of a newline if used with TextField. I have also tried accessing the wrappedValue of the bound string to no avail. What am I missing here?

---

Edit: I'm not interested in a multiline input. I'm interested in a single line input like "hello\nworld". However, when I capture "hello\nworld" in a bound variable through a TextField, I am not seeing the output I expect, which is hello then a newline then world. Instead, I am seeing the string exactly as it was input: hello\nworld.

Comment: Are you saying that the user would actually type "hello\nworld" (including the "\" and the "n") and then you want to convert that to a newline character?

Comment: That's right. And that's normally what happens anyway if you just have Text("hello\nworld").

Comment: To clarify: "hello" and "world" on separate lines, just as you would expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to take a user-entered String of "Hello\nworld" (which would read as an escaped string as "Hello\nworld") and replace a literal (non-escaped) "\n" with the a newline character.

This would do that:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var inputText: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("foo", text: $inputText)
            Text(inputText.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\n", with: "\n"))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you. Though I'm not fully understanding why the extra backslash is needed here — or rather, why "\n" is read as a literal here when it is usually just processed as a newline character.

Comment: When the user types "\n", it is considered by the system to be two characters -- "\" and "n". This is different than when we use `\n` in our code, which is a shorthand that tells the compiler to put in a newline character. By using the second backslash, we tell the compiler to *not* treat the following slash as part of a newline character and instead as just a regular "\" character.